# Excel - Referencing a cell in another sheet depending on its value

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here is my situation. I have two sheets. They are in a certain format, like this:

1.

```
| Id-Number | Id-Name |
```

2.

```
| Id-Number | Id-Other Value |
```

I would like to take "Id-OtherValue" and add it after "Id-Name" in the first sheet.
I was thinking of doing it like this:

```
| Id-Number | Id-Name | (Get "Id-Other Value" from Sheet 2 where Id-Number = Id-Number)
```

I realize I could just copy the values over by hand. But I will be in this situation in the future and I want to save myself some time.

Is there a way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is a vLookup of the data in Sheet2 from Sheet1.

On Sheet1, where you want "ID-Other-Value" use the below formula,

```
=vlookup(A2, Sheet2!A$2:B$4, 2, FALSE)
```

**Assumptions:**

- A2 -> Contains the ID in sheet1
- A2 to B4 - > Contains the ID in Column A and ID-Other-Value in Column B (On Sheet2)

Modify the range of Sheet2 accordingly in the formula and copy paste it across all the cells you want it to be populated in Sheet1.

**Edit:** *If range_lookup (the last parameter in the formula), is TRUE the first column specified in the range (Sheet2) is to be sorted. There is no sort requirement, if the range_lookup is FALSE.*

Comment: @LDC3: If the range_lookup is FALSE, the first column is not required to be sorted.

Comment: If you put your comment in your answer, I'll delete this comment.

Comment: @LDC3: That's absolutely fine to leave your comments as is, it will only help provide more clarity for someone who is going to look it up at a later point of time. Anyways, have added a bit more about the range_lookup in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If some of your Id-Number in Column A on sheet 1, aren't present in Column A on Sheet 2, you will get an ERROR Value, if so, you may use ISERROR function combined with IF function, this will protect you from error messages like #DIV0 or #VALUE and any other error message generated by a faulty formula.

IF(ISERROR(vlookup(A2, Sheet2!A$2:B$4, 2, FALSE)),0,vlookup(A2, Sheet2!A$2:B$4, 2, FALSE)) where 0 value will the result instead the error message.

In Excel 2010 you may use IFERROR function instead, but if you share your work to somebody with earlier versions it will not work, so this oldie functions combined will work in all versions.